# Fail2Ban установлен в HOST для ограничение DOCKER

Tags: nginx, docker, iptables, fail2ban

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья!
Как уже писал в заголовке есть хост на котором установлен Fail2Ban, есть настройки *jail.local*:

```
[nginx-noscript] 
 
enabled = true 
chain = DOCKER-USER 
filter = nginx-noscript 
port = http, https 
logpath = /log/nginx/access.log 
bantime = 365 
maxretry = 3 
action = iptables-allports[]
```

В логах пишет что работает в поте лица и успешно банит:

```
fail2ban.jail           [11559]: INFO    Jail 'nginx-noscript' started
fail2ban.filter         [11559]: INFO    [nginx-noscript] Found 192.168.1.47
fail2ban.actions        [11559]: NOTICE  [nginx-noscript] Ban 192.168.1.47
```

А вот при повторной попытке зайти на деле бан не останавливает:

```
fail2ban.filter         [11559]: INFO    [nginx-noscript] Found 192.168.1.47
fail2ban.filter         [11559]: INFO    [nginx-noscript] Found 192.168.1.47
fail2ban.filter         [11559]: INFO    [nginx-noscript] Found 192.168.1.47
fail2ban.filter         [11559]: INFO    [nginx-noscript] Found 192.168.1.47
fail2ban.actions        [11559]: NOTICE  [nginx-noscript] 192.168.1.47 already banned
```

Соответственно уведомляет об уже забаненом IP и пропускает. Дело в том что сам NGINX находится на хосте и в DOCKER контейнере.
В таблице появляется запись но вероятно не в той цепочке:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    f2b-nginx-noscript  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10   ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.4           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-nginx-noscript (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REJECT     all  --  192.168.1.47         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2    RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Были испробованы такие методы как:

```
chain = INPUT
```

```
chain = FORWARD
```

Результат получается, вернее результата нет.
Будте любезны, подскажите как еще можно решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить `chain` для banning action таким способом невозможно - параметры из `jail` больше не передаются если `action` тоже переопределена в `jail.local`.
См. [jail.conf#L174 (action_)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/92f90038fa67d719c55c75f5eff8059e849fe747/config/jail.conf#L174) и [jail.conf#L216 (action)](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.10/config/jail.conf#L216).
Переписывая `action` (или `action_`) интерполяция параметра `%(chain)s` отсутвует и передача параметра более не происходит, т.е. установка `chain = DOCKER-USER` и д.р. не работают в итоговой конфигурации (action использует собственные настройки по умолчанию, т.е. INPUT для chain).

Т.е. либо:

```
chain = DOCKER-USER 
# need to set banaction (not action):
banaction = iptables-allports
```

либо:

```
# need to supply all parameters directly:
action = iptables-allports[chain=DOCKER-USER, ...другие-параметры-необходимые-для-action...]
```

Проверить что получилось, можно с помощью:
`fail2ban-client -d | grep 'nginx-noscript.*action'`
или
`fail2ban-client --dp`

Answer (score -1):

**Спасибо дорогие друзья за помощь!**
**ОБНОВИЛ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ!**
Для тех кто столкнулся с данной проблемой вопрос решается <strike>путем добавления в */etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-allports.conf*</strike>

```
[Init] 
#port = http, https 
#protocol = tcp 
#chain = DOCKER-USER
```

**Исключил вышеупомянутые строки в iptables-allports.conf**
Соответственно в <strike>*jail.conf*</strike> *jail.local* по вашим рекомендациям прекрасно отработали следующие строки:

```
[nginx-noscript]
enabled = true 
filter = nginx-noscript 
port = http, https 

# Путь к файлу с логами из docker контейнера #
logpath = /home/user/app/log/nginx/access.log 

bantime = 1d
maxretry = 3 
action = iptables-allports[chain=DOCKER-USER]
```

Comment: 1) в случае установки chain напрямую в `action.d/iptables-allports`, все chain независимо от jail будут помещены в DOCKER-USER, т.е. если sshd или какой другой сервис например не в докере, FORWARD для них не работает, и пакеты не попадут в DOCKER-USER совсем 2) port и protocol не действуют для iptables-allports (это только для multiport actions); 3) Нельзя править *.conf напрямую (может переписаться при апгрейде) - нужно писать всё кастомное в *.local);